# get/set a song tag in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, tags, media-player, mediaelement

I want to change the song tag. For example the Song album is Sunshine and it wasn't correct, how can I hardcode to change to song album of particular song?
I have look over the msdn library but couldn't find any appropriate method, any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit the metadata for songs directly on the phone. Not with the build-in player, nor with the API.

Comment: There is no way to fix or override the ID3 tag for a song with hard code?

Comment: how do you seem so sure, do you have any official document? :( it's possible on iPhone...